# Why php array gets slower with newer php versions, and how to go around that?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, memory, migration

I have a php based system working perfectly since 2006, which has a backend (CLI, cron) process, processing millions of records, using a big tree-like structure in memory.

I've noticed great performance regressions when upgrading a debian machine.

So, to research the issue, I wrote a simple script, and downloaded a dozen xampp releases, and run the same script with the different php versions.

```
$start=microtime(true);
$n=10;
$counter=1;
$testarray=Array();

for ($i[1]=0;$i[1]<$n;$i[1]++) 
  for ($i[2]=0;$i[2]<$n;$i[2]++) 
    for ($i[3]=0;$i[3]<$n;$i[3]++) 
      for ($i[4]=0;$i[4]<$n;$i[4]++) 
        for ($i[5]=0;$i[5]<$n;$i[5]++) 
          for ($i[6]=0;$i[6]<$n;$i[6]++) 
            for ($i[7]=0;$i[7]<$n;$i[7]++) 
              $testarray[$i[1]][$i[2]][$i[3]][$i[4]][$i[5]][$i[6]][$i[7]]=$counter++;

$end=microtime(true);
echo "PHP ".phpversion()." ".round(memory_get_peak_usage(true)/(1024*1024),2)." mbyte max ram, ".round($end-$start,2)." seconds\r\n";
```

I run the same script against xampp win32 1.6.0a through win32 1.7.7-vc9, with the following results:

```
 - PHP 5.2.1 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.43 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.1 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.37 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.2 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.43 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.3 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.38 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.4 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.5 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.5 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.28 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.5 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.31 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.6 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.52 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.6 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.54 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.8 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.72 seconds
 - PHP 5.2.9 890.25 mbyte max ram, 12.53 seconds
 - PHP 5.3.0 975.5 mbyte max ram, 18.28 seconds
 - PHP 5.3.1 975.5 mbyte max ram, 18.06 seconds
 - PHP 5.3.5 975.5 mbyte max ram, 18.49 seconds
 - PHP 5.3.8 975.5 mbyte max ram, 17.97 seconds
 - PHP 5.3.8 975.5 mbyte max ram, 18.11 seconds
```

Notes:
 - I don't use xampp or windows on servers, but this was the easiest way to test through different versions at once.
 - I tried to google for this problem a few times, but didn't get any relevant results
 - The speed loss is about the same (50% longer runtime) on the servers
 - I don't think that a slowdown of this kind is acceptable from any framework or compiler,  - even in spite of new features the old ones should work just as well as before. I can't tell my boss, that the same computer with the same software can't do the same job anymore, because we dist-upgraded the debian on it... That would look like some windows upgrade. :)

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow just to install all that php versions you spent  lot of time i believe. you could just test 2-3 releases

Comment: Extremely ugly loop aside, I am not entirely sure why other than maybe one (or more) of the PHP extensions that are being installed with XAMMP bloats the performance like crazy. Yikes, with most of my code I have seen things speed up. The first thought that comes to mind would be that maybe the newer version works better with object orientation.

Comment: How the hell did you install all these releases?

Comment: Have you tested with 5.4 yet? My own experience is that it's significantly faster than 5.3

Comment: are you running your site on windows? if not the results are meaningless. the OS plays a significant role. you can't extrapolate from one to another

Comment: Of course I didn't run the site on windows, it was just a tool to show the differences between the php versions. It was easy to download a lot of xampps to directories and run each. Under linux, testing (downloading and building) a dozen php versions would require more effort. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call [gc_disable](http://www.php.net/gc_disable)() before the loop. Cuts my time in half.

(php added a new garbage collector in 5.3)

Comment: I know about the gc, but I didn't know, that it works like a handbrake, even if I don't release any memory. 

 Turning it off looks like a good idea, thanks.

 I'll have to try to enable-disable it runtime in different parts of the code, as I don't want to leak too much memory. I see the PHP 5.3 runtimes drop to around 11 sec on the test machine, so it's a little bit faster than 5.2 was before.

Comment: It also unlocks a community easter egg on [github thread](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/ac676f47f7bbc619678a29deae097b6b0710b799)